# Check if Windows 8 app is running in assigned access mode

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps, kiosk

in an Windows Store App to do exams I need to know if the app or the user is running in Windows Assigned access mode.

Is there any way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet will help you do that.

```
 LockApplicationHost host = LockApplicationHost.GetForCurrentView();
                if (null == host)
                {
                   //You are not on assigned access
                }
                else
                {
                  // Assigned access mode
                }
```